# Homology groups of the Klein bottle

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra

I've seen [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7334/homology-of-the-klein-bottle) but didn't really understand the answer. So here is what I tried:

[image]

According to this picture we have one 0-simplex - $[v]$, two 1-simplices - $[v,v]_a,[v,v]_b$ and two 2-simplices - $[v,v,v]_U,[v,v,v]_L$.

**The chain complexes**

$C_0=\{nv:n\in\Bbb{Z}\}, C_1=\{n[v,v]_a+m[v,v]_b+k[v,v]_c:n,m,k\in\Bbb{Z}\}, C_2=\{n[v,v,v]_U+m[v,v,v]_L:n,m\in\Bbb{Z}\}$.

**Boundary maps**

$∂_0=0, ∂_1([v,v]_a)=[v]-[v]=0$,

$∂_2([v,v,v]_U)=[v,v]_a+[v,v]_b-[v,v]_c=[v,v]_a$ and $∂_2([v,v,v]_L)=[v,v]_a-[v,v]_b+[v,v]_c=[v,v]_a$.

I think $\operatorname{Im}∂_2$ is the set of multiples of $[v,v]$ which is isomorphic to $\Bbb{Z}$ but I'm not sure about this. Once I know $\operatorname{Im}∂_2$ it's easy to calculate $\ker{∂_1}/\operatorname{Im}∂_2=H_1(K)$ as $\ker{∂_1}=\Bbb{Z}^3$.

Could you explain what is $\operatorname{Im}∂_2$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You obviously have a typo, having forgotten to include the $1$-simplex $c$. Your "simplifications" of $\partial_2$ are incorrect. To save typing, I'll write $\partial_2 U = a+b-c$ and $\partial_2 L= a-b+c$. If you make the change of basis (over $\mathbb Z$) $a'=a+b-c$, $b'=b-c$, $c'=c$, you can easily check that $a', a'-2b'$ give a basis for $\text{im}\,\partial_2$. So $H_1 \cong \mathbb Z\oplus \mathbb Z/2$.

Comment: Why are my simplifications of $\partial_2$ incorrect?

Comment: Because the three $1$-simplices $a$, $b$, and $c$ are all independent — they're the generators of $C_1\cong\mathbb Z^3$.

Answer (score 2):

It seems it is a long way from being accepted that to write the boundary of the diagram

[image: klein]

we need write only the **nonabelian** formula (assuming base point the top left corner)

$$\delta \sigma= b +a -b +a $$

saving all that decomposition into simplices. For more information see my presentation at [Chicago, 2012](https://groupoids.org.uk/pdffiles/chicago-beamer-handout.pdf).  It is also true that it does require new ideas to make a complete story, like crossed modules, free crossed modules ($\sigma$ is a generator of a free crossed module, and $a,b$ generate a free group), and the complete story is in the book ["Nonabelian algebraic topology", 2011, EMS Tract 15](https://groupoids.org.uk/nonab-a-t.html).  Other presentations (2014, 2015)  are on my [preprint page](https://groupoids.org.uk/brownpr.html) (Galway, Aveiro, Liverpool,...). All this stems from and develops the work of J.H.C. Whitehead in his paper "Combinatorial Homotopy II".